# Enable B2B Commerce in Existing Salesforce Org

Tags: migration, sales-cloud, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce, b2b

We have a requirement, where one of the customers is using Sales Cloud with objects like Leads, Opportunity, Product, Pricebook, etc.

Now they would like to use B2B commerce. We have a **question** regarding this:

- Is it possible to enable B2B Commerce in existing Sales Cloud by purchasing additional licenses? By this, we don't need to migrate the Data of Product, Pricebooks, etc.
- Or the only way is to procure a new B2B commerce instance and integrate it with Sales org or migrate the users/data from Sales Cloud to B2B commerce cloud?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Salesforce Account Executives are the best people to reach out to for License related queries, cost, and org planning, and please confirm with them.

From my knowledge,

- You can certainly enable B2B Commerce Lightning features in the same org if you have additional [licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.b2b_commerce_license.htm&type=5). It is meant to be in the same org and no need for a multi org solution. This is all explained [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/b2b-commerce-basics/get-started-with-b2b-commerce).

Note that if you are planning to use the Visualforce version then you will get a Managed package to install while for the Lightning version all you need is to enable few features as documented [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/b2b_standalone_setup.pdf).

Keep in mind that B2B commerce license pricing is based on a number of orders in the system rather than a license cost. So you would need to be mindful of that as it affects the cost.

Comment: Mohith, As always thanks for your helpful answer.
So our understanding is that the same product/pricebooks objects can be used. We are already using this in our implementation. Maybe, we will need to tweak them but we can use the same for all purposes. As you suggested we will also reach out to the SF AE.